# Magento 2 - Layered Navigation is not coming on search pages

Tags: magento2, layout, template, layered-navigation, magento2.2

> Issue - Layered navigation Disappeared on Search Pages if Layout is Changed to 1column

Worked Around - Override

> catalogsearch_result_index.xml in Magento_CatalogSearch
>
> Change layout="1column" for showing Layered Navigation on top

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <attribute name="class" value="page-products"/>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\Result" name="search.result" template="Magento_CatalogSearch::result.phtml" cacheable="false">
            <block class="Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\SearchResult\ListProduct" name="search_result_list" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml" cacheable="false">
                <arguments>
                    <!-- If argument's position depends on image size changeable in VDE:
                    positions:list-secondary,grid-secondary,list-actions,grid-actions,list-primary,grid-primary
                -->
                    <argument name="positioned" xsi:type="string">positions:list-secondary</argument>
                </arguments>
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/toolbar.phtml" cacheable="false">
                    <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager" cacheable="false"/>
                </block>
                <action method="setToolbarBlockName">
                    <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">product_list_toolbar</argument>
                </action>
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\RendererList" name="category.product.type.details.renderers" as="details.renderers">
                    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="category.product.type.details.renderers.default" as="default"/>
                </block>
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Container" name="catalogsearch.product.addto" as="addto">
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\AddTo\Compare"
                           name="catalogsearch.product.addto.compare" as="compare"
                           template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/addto/compare.phtml"/>
                </block>
            </block>
            <action method="setListOrders"/>
            <action method="setListModes"/>
            <action method="setListCollection"/>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

> On Category Pages - layout="1column" is working perfect for showing Layered Navigation on Top

Screenshot of Layered Navigation on Category Pages - [image]
Result

> On Search Pages -
>
> 1. Show Layered Navigation on top if Layout is changed from "2columns-left" to "1column"
> 2. Layered Navigation is Showing and Working Perfectly in Left Sidebar under layout="2columns-left"